# PostgreSQL making winsock TCP recv command incredibly slow

Tags: c, postgresql, winsock2, libpq

I am writing a piece of C based software using Visual C++ 2008 Express.

The software has a database POSTGRESQL 9.4 and multiple TCP sockets (both Server and Client).

The sockets are created by the method on this link.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737593(v=vs.85).aspx

Issue i have is soon as i connect to the database.

```
*conn = PQconnectdb(name);
if (PQstatus(*conn) != CONNECTION_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Connection to database failed: %s\n",
            PQerrorMessage(*conn));
    PQfinish(*conn);
    return DB_CONNECTION_ERROR;
}
```

My winsock recv commands grind to a halt.

Is their any compatibility issues between winsock2 and postgresql 9.4 or do i need to initialise them in a certain way?.

Thanks

Comment: Details are lacking. Are you making the libpq connection in a different thread in the same process? In the same thread as part of an event loop? In a different process? What does the stack look like on your winsock recv call when it "grinds to a halt" (use a debugger)?

Comment: Each socket connection has its own thread, the initial database connection occurs in the main thread, will look at the stack trace